# Images shown only when files are included in the project

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, converters

I have a wpf application in which I use a converter to set the image source. Here's the code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding Path=MyItem.MyItemId, Converter={StaticResource ImageSourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=MyItems}" Width="150" Height="150"></Image>
```

And the C# code:

```
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Concat(@"..\Images\" + System.Convert.ToString(parameter) + "\\", System.Convert.ToString(value).Trim(), ".png");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

And this works when the images are included in my project. That is not good enough. In the future the user will upload images and I can't include all of them in the project. How can I make the images to be shown even when the .png files won't be included in the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Images folder is residing in the application directory then in the value converter try constructing the Image URI as

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Images\" + System.Convert.ToString(parameter) + "\\", System.Convert.ToString(value).Trim(), ".png");
```

Comment: The images aren't in bin. The Images folder is in the same leves als bin.

Comment: Use Path.GetDirectoryName appropriately on AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get to the folder level you want to reach where Images folder is present. But you may end up in trouble to accomplish your goal if the Images are kept in the Installation Directory since User Access Control will not let you to keep the user files in the C:\Program Files. Better to reserve a space in the Application Data folder for you and Instead of System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) to construct the path to your Images folder.

Answer (score 0):

For accomplishing this, first you will have to decide where you want to keep you images so that your application can access these images and also in future user can upload images to this location.

It will be better if you use the absolute path of the upload folder, and access all image from there only.